# Using make_column_transformer for categorical variables giving error during fit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn

The problem is multivariate linear regression. X having 8 categorical variables and balance are categorical with encoded as 0 and 1.

When tried to build column transformer and fit the rows giving the below error.
'TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index''

```
cat_cols=df_train.select_dtypes(include="object").columns

y.head()

0    130.81
1     88.53
2     76.26
3     80.62
4     78.02
Name: y, dtype: float64

X.head()

X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8  X10 X11 ... X375    X376    X377    X378    X379    X380    X382    X383    X384    X385
0   k   v   at  a   d   u   j   o   0   0   ... 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   k   t   av  e   d   y   l   o   0   0   ... 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   az  w   n   c   d   x   j   x   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   az  t   n   f   d   x   l   e   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   az  v   n   f   d   h   d   n   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5 rows × 376 columns

ct=make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),[cat_cols]),remainder='passthrough')

ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                  transformers=[('onehotencoder',
                                 OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),
                                 [Index(['X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X8'], dtype='object')])])

    
ct.fit(X_train)
```

Error at this stage

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-180-8ea255dead4d> in <module>
----> 1 ct.fit(X_train)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit(self, X, y)
    492         # we use fit_transform to make sure to set sparse_output_ (for which we
    493         # need the transformed data) to have consistent output type in predict
--> 494         self.fit_transform(X, y=y)
    495         return self
    496 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in fit_transform(self, X, y)
    527         self._validate_transformers()
    528         self._validate_column_callables(X)
--> 529         self._validate_remainder(X)
    530 
    531         result = self._fit_transform(X, y, _fit_transform_one)

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in _validate_remainder(self, X)
    317 
    318         # Make it possible to check for reordered named columns on transform
--> 319         self._has_str_cols = any(_determine_key_type(cols) == 'str'
    320                                  for cols in self._columns)
    321         if hasattr(X, 'columns'):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\compose\_column_transformer.py in <genexpr>(.0)
    317 
    318         # Make it possible to check for reordered named columns on transform
--> 319         self._has_str_cols = any(_determine_key_type(cols) == 'str'
    320                                  for cols in self._columns)
    321         if hasattr(X, 'columns'):

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\__init__.py in _determine_key_type(key, accept_slice)
    256         return key_stop_type
    257     if isinstance(key, (list, tuple)):
--> 258         unique_key = set(key)
    259         key_type = {_determine_key_type(elt) for elt in unique_key}
    260         if not key_type:

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __hash__(self)
   3905 
   3906     def __hash__(self):
-> 3907         raise TypeError(f"unhashable type: {repr(type(self).__name__)}")
   3908 
   3909     def __setitem__(self, key, value):

TypeError: unhashable type: 'Index'
```

Again tried to use OneHot encoder on only 8 categorical variables and used fit_transform for some rows as a sample ,it got inverse transformed to original.So for categorical with alphabets as values it is working fine.Since the other columns after X8 is already available in 0 and 1 directly passed in the transformer.

When i tried to use OHE for the entire data set X and pass to the linear regression it is giving error as below during

```
ohe=OneHotEncoder()
X_train_transformed=ohe.fit_transform(X_train)
ohe.categories_

array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'], dtype=object),
 array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'], dtype=object),
 array(['aa', 'ab', 'ac', 'ad', 'ae', 'af', 'ag', 'ah', 'c', 'd', 'f', 'g',
        'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 'v',
        'w', 'x', 'y'], dtype=object),
 array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l'],
       dtype=object),
 array(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm',
        'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y'],
       dtype=object),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),
 array([0, 1], dtype=int64),

linereg=LinearRegression()
linereg.fit(X_train_transformed,y_train)
X_test_transformed=ohe.fit_transform(X_test)
X_train_transformed.shape
(2946, 906)
X_test_transformed.shape
(1263, 872)
linereg.predict(X_test_transformed)
ValueError: dimension mismatch
```

Not sure why the dimensions are transformed train and test.

Appreciate your help to resolve this are changing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first problem, I believe it comes from the declaration of the column transformer. When you provide the columns on which the Transformer should operate you provide them as a list of list (by using the `[]` in  `[cat_cols]`). I did a test on my side and removing the `[]` resolves the problem for me, as such:

```
ct = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(), cat_cols), remainder = 'passthrough')
```

Regarding your second problem, I believe the dimensions for the test and the train data are different because you fitted OHE on the test data before transforming. The test data should only be transformed and not fitted, as such:

```
X_test_transformed = ohe.transform(X_test)
```

When you fit the transformer again on the test data, what I think that happens in your case is that there are categorical columns that contain fewer groups for the test data than for the train data and thus some dummy columns will not be created, which makes the transformed test data to have fewer columns than the transformed train data.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. I could fit the regression. But when i do the predict it is giving error.   ` X_train_transformed.shape  (2946, 906)  X_test_transformed=ohe.transform(X_test)  X_test_transformed.shape (1263, 872)   linereg.predict(X_test_transformed)  `ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 906 is different from 872)` ---- obviously error due to shape (columns) mismatch. How to go about now.

Comment: Please suggest. @Roberto There is a problem here .I am suppose to use the column transformed object on the test set. When i use the same i get error  `X_test_transformed=ct.transform(X_test)  linereg.predict(X_test_transformed)  
  ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 906 is different from 544)`

Comment: I am sorry @Ins_hunter it is a bit hard to reproduce your problem without a [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). In the case you use the `column transformer` I guess you only fit it on the training data? Does your train and test data have the same shape before transforming either of them?

Comment: The shapes are as below. @Roberto     Before transformation.`X_train.shape (2946, 376) X_train_transformed.shape (2946, 558)                                                      
 X_test.shape (1263, 376)                                                                         X_test_transformed.shape (1263, 544)` -Any suggestions would be helpful ???

Comment: 8 columns are nominal categorical values (strings) and balance columns are all binary (1 or 0) values only.  @Roberto

Comment: I am not able to reproduce the problem on my side @Ins_hunter. If I follow these steps I get arrays of the same shape:
1. Create `ohe = OneHotEncoder()` 
2. `fit` the object to the train data
3. `transform` the train data with the `ohe` object
4. `transform` the test data with the `ohe` object

The advise I can give you is to modify your question (or create a new one) using a MRE, as mentioned  in prev comment. A MRE is basically the minimum amount of code to reproduce your error, so it can be used by someone else on their side. If you create a new question you can send me the link here

Comment: Thanks @ Roberto . As advised i had created a new link for the issue. I am new to stackoverflow and not sure whether any way to share the data set so that i can share the portion. Hope the new question i created shall serve as MRE. Eager to hear from you.`(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64673064/shape-gets-changed-when-preprocessing-with-column-transformer-and-predicting-the)`