# Shape gets changed when preprocessing with column transformer and predicting the testing data

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, linear-regression

The data structure is like below.

```
df_train.head()

ID  y   X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8  ... X375    X376    X377    X378    X379    X380    X382    X383    X384    X385
0   0   130.81  k   v   at  a   d   u   j   o   ... 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   6   88.53   k   t   av  e   d   y   l   o   ... 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   7   76.26   az  w   n   c   d   x   j   x   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   9   80.62   az  t   n   f   d   x   l   e   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   13  78.02   az  v   n   f   d   h   d   n   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0

df_train.shape
(4209, 378)

df_train.info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 4209 entries, 0 to 4208
Columns: 378 entries, ID to X385
dtypes: float64(1), int64(369), object(8)
memory usage: 12.1+ MB

cat_cols=df_train.select_dtypes(include="object").columns

y=df_train['y']

y.shape
(4209,)
y.head()
0    130.81
1     88.53
2     76.26
3     80.62
4     78.02
Name: y, dtype: float64

X=df_train.drop(['y','ID'],axis=1)
X.shape
(4209, 376)

X.head()
X0  X1  X2  X3  X4  X5  X6  X8  X10 X11 ... X375    X376    X377    X378    X379    X380    X382    X383    X384    X385
0   k   v   at  a   d   u   j   o   0   0   ... 0   0   1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
1   k   t   av  e   d   y   l   o   0   0   ... 1   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
2   az  w   n   c   d   x   j   x   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0
3   az  t   n   f   d   x   l   e   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
4   az  v   n   f   d   h   d   n   0   0   ... 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0
5 rows × 376 columns

X_train,X_test,y_train,y_test = train_test_split(X,y,test_size=0.3,random_state=42)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)
(2946, 376)
(1263, 376)
(2946,)
(1263,)


ct=make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(),cat_cols),remainder='passthrough')
ct
ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                  transformers=[('onehotencoder', OneHotEncoder(),
                                 Index(['X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X8'], dtype='object'))])
X_train.columns
Index(['X0', 'X1', 'X2', 'X3', 'X4', 'X5', 'X6', 'X8', 'X10', 'X11',
       ...
       'X375', 'X376', 'X377', 'X378', 'X379', 'X380', 'X382', 'X383', 'X384',
       'X385'],
      dtype='object', length=376)

type(X_train)
pandas.core.frame.DataFrame

X_train_transformed=ct.fit_transform(X_train)
(2946, 558)
type(X_train_transformed)
numpy.ndarray

linereg=LinearRegression()
linereg.fit(X_train_transformed,y_train)
X_test_transformed=ct.fit_transform(X_test)
X_test.shape
(1263, 376)
X_test_transformed.shape
(1263, 544)
linereg.predict(X_test_transformed)
```

Error faced at this step (last extract shared here).

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-126-9d1b72421dd0> in <module>

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py in inner_f(*args, **kwargs)
     71                           FutureWarning)
     72         kwargs.update({k: arg for k, arg in zip(sig.parameters, args)})
---> 73         return f(**kwargs)
     74     return inner_f
     75 

D:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\extmath.py in safe_sparse_dot(a, b, dense_output)
    151             ret = np.dot(a, b)
    152     else:
--> 153         ret = a @ b
    154 
    155     if (sparse.issparse(a) and sparse.issparse(b)

ValueError: matmul: Input operand 1 has a mismatch in its core dimension 0, with gufunc signature (n?,k),(k,m?)->(n?,m?) (size 558 is different from 544)
```

The shape is getting distorted while transforming the data set. Not sure whether any better way for preprocessing the data in this case as all columns are categorical.There are 8 columns of nominal categorical data values as strings and balance all columns have binary values only. THe column transformer had used One Hot Encoder and balance columns were passed directly to the predictor.Appreciate your help to resolve this .

Comment: @Roberto - `Can we use Column Transformer before splitting the data set to Train and Test. Is it the right approach`.If it do i get the results predicted.Appreciate your response.But i need  good accuracy of prediction.                                                           
`Also  Can regularisation be applied for data set with fully categorical variables`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried to create a Minimal Reproducible Example of your problem, and I do not run into any errors myself. Can you run it on your side? See if there are any important differences between the dataframe created here and yours?

Note that:

- When transforming your test data, you should only transform the data with the `ColumnTransformer` and not fit it
- The `OneHotEncoder` is initialized with `handle_unknown = 'ignore'`

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
from sklearn.compose import make_column_transformer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

# Parameters to tweak
n_categories = 10 # Number of categorical columns
groups_by_cat = [3 , 10] # Number of groups which a category will have, to be chosen 
                        # randomly between these two numbers
n_rows = 20
n_binary_cols = 10

# code
list_alpha = list('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')
np.random.seed(42)
groups = []

# names of the columns of the dataframe
col_names = ['X'+str(i) for i in range(n_categories + n_binary_cols)]

# first we generate randomly a set of groups that each category can have
for i in range(n_categories):
    np.random.randn()
    temp_groups = []
    temp_n_groups = np.random.randint(*groups_by_cat)
    for k in range(temp_n_groups):
        group = "".join(np.random.choice(list_alpha,2, replace = True))
        temp_groups.append(group)
    groups.append(temp_groups)

# then we generate n_rows taking samples from the groups generated previously
array_categories = np.random.choice(groups[0],(n_rows,1), replace = True)
for i in range(1,n_categories):
    temp_column = np.random.choice(groups[i],(n_rows,1), replace = True)
    array_categories = np.hstack((array_categories, temp_column))
    

# we generate an array containing the binary columns
array_binaries = np.random.randint(0, 2, (n_rows, n_binary_cols))


# we create the dataframe concatenating together the two arrays
df = pd.DataFrame(np.hstack((array_categories, array_binaries)), columns = col_names)

y = np.random.random_sample((n_rows,1))

# split
X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(df, y)

print(X_train.shape)
print(X_test.shape)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

# create column transformer
cat_cols = df.select_dtypes(include="object").columns
ct = make_column_transformer((OneHotEncoder(handle_unknown='ignore'),cat_cols),
                             remainder='passthrough')

# fit transform the ColumnTransformer
X_train_transformed = ct.fit_transform(X_train)

# fit linearRegression and predict
linereg = LinearRegression()
linereg.fit(X_train_transformed,y_train)
X_test_transformed = ct.transform(X_test)

print("\nSizes of transformed arrays")
print(X_train_transformed.shape)
print(X_test_transformed.shape)

linereg.predict(X_test_transformed)
```

Note that the test data, is only transformed with the `ColumnTransformer`:

```
X_test_transformed = ct.transform(X_test)
```

Otherwise the `OneHotEncoder()` will calculate again the necessary columns for your test data, which might not be exactly the same columns than for your training data (if for example the test data does not have some of the groups that were found on your training data). [Here](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/12321/whats-the-difference-between-fit-and-fit-transform-in-scikit-learn-models) you have more information in the differences between `fit` `fit_transform` and `transform`

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.@Roberto  Is it advisable to use the column transformer prior to split. If i do like that i could proceed with fit and predict of the model. But not sure whether we can do that way??  I tried to use only transform of Test data but encountered the same dimension issue of the matrix.   Your veiws please on whether we can proceed to use column transformer prior to train/test split.

Comment: @Ins_hunter, in general, you should not use the column transformer prior to split, to avoid any data leakage. However, in this particular case where you are only creating dummy features I do not think there are any problems with proceeding that way, but I am no expert so I might be wrong. I am going to edit my answer with a MRE, you can run that on your side and we see what happens, to try to understand the problem

Comment: Many Thanks @Roberto  for your great efforts to build MRE.  The df is of the same structure, values as well.Sorry i could not do the same. I got your point and was a great learning experience.I also need to remove some columns having zero variance from the data set which i did prior to split. The shape isssue resolved to build model.

Comment: (Had to give split comments due to space limitations)I had tried to model,but not getting a respectable r2 score on the test set.Score values train/test provided model wise. Any suggestions to bring the test score equivalent to a respectable train score as i am a novice.Score values  train/test model wise.@Roberto

Comment: Score values  train/test model wise.@RobertoLinearreg(0.66/-7.81),Ridge(0.66,0.43),Lasso(0.65,0.47),Elasticnet (0.38,0.30) and then did PCA(reduced from transformed 541 columns to 135) and applied XGBoost  (0.98,0.30). Not sure whether we can use PCA for categorical variables. Any steps am i missing in preprocessing of the data or any tuning in the model required to improve the score .Thanks in advance for any guidance. @Roberto

Comment: @Ins_hunter, good that you could learn something. I have not understood if your problem of shape mismatch is resolved or not, and if it is resolved what solved it.

Comment: As to your questions on the model, according to Comments help: _"Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post."_ So I don't think this is the place to ask all those questions, you should probably create a new question. Some quick guidance though, it seems to me your models might be overfitting, because you have too many features after OneHotEncodding. You can look at this [course](https://www.kaggle.com/learn/feature-engineering) for some help

Comment: Thanks. I followed your code and shape issue solved. Thank you very much for your support @ Roberto